# datepicker Is not showing?

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-bootstrap4

I am developing an application with Django and I need to choose date and time. I am trying to do it with **'bootstrap_datepicker_plus'**, but the calendar does not appear when I show the form.

**settings.py**

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'hungryFalconryApp',
    'rest_framework',
    'bootstrap4',
    'bootstrap_datepicker_plus',
]

BOOTSTRAP4 = {
    'include_jquery': True,
}
```

**forms.py**

```py
from django import forms
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import DateTimePickerInput

class DateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comedero
        fields = ('dias', 'horas')

        widgets = {
            'dias': DateTimePickerInput(),
            'horas': DateTimePickerInput(),
        }
```

**views.py**

```py
def programar_comederos(request, nombre):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DateForm(request.POST)
        print(nombre)
        if(form.is_valid()):
            comedero = form.save(commit=False)
            print(comedero.dias)
            print(comedero.horas)
    else:
        form = DateForm()
    return render(request, 'hungryFalconryApp/programar_comederos.html',{'nombre': nombre, 'form':form})
```

**template.html**

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
{% bootstrap_messages %}
{{ form.media }}
{% block content %}
<form action="" method="post" class="form">

            {% csrf_token %}
            {% bootstrap_form form %}
            {% bootstrap_button "Guardar" button_type="submit" button_class="btn-primary" %}
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Do you use any javascript calendar library ???

Comment: I prefer to use django packages, to learn

Answer (score 1):

I have already solved. In [django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/) it indicates putting {{form.media}} after this code but {{form.media}} must go inside the  tag

Answer (score 1):

you can also use Datepicker too, Datepicker is jqueryUI, its faster and also reliable

**[see example here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)**

you just cdn or jqueryUI file in your project

**`jqueryUI CDN`**

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

then assign Id to that particular field

```
<script>
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd M yy' });

</script>
```

**" datepicker " is html id** you also change date format from **`dateFormat`**

Comment: you  got solution